# Can everyone recite Aditya Hridayam Stotra?

Tags: mantras, astrology, stotra

If someone has sun in the 9th house, should they chant Aditya Hridayam Stotra?

I met two astrologers and they gave opposite advice and I am confused.

One said - it will help the sun get powerful.

Another said - because your sun is weak and it's not in good house - chanting it will be make it strong in wrong house.

Which advice should I follow?

[In hindi language.](https://jaihinduism.com/aditya-hridaya-stotra/)

Comment: Even if Sun is strong in your chart you will still get benefits by chanting the stotra .. it will make the Sun stronger so to speak

Comment: @Rickross are there such stotras for all grahas?

Comment: Yes thee are but difficult to find on net @Rudra But Navagraha stotras and Kavachams are easily available on net for all Grahas.

Answer (score 0):

This answer turned out long, so you can skip to the conclusion **in bold**, if needed.

> If someone has sun in the 9th house, should they chant Aditya Hridayam Stotra?

This is like asking: "If someone has legs should he run a marathon"?

You're missing out- the Lagna, in particular. Which Raashi is Surya in?

Who has Drshti on him? Whose Dashaa is running? Whose Nakshatra is he in? Is he with someone else? And, which Raashi is he in, also matters, but that is covered by Lagna anyways.

> I met two astrologers and they gave opposite advice and I am confused.

They both gave you the correct conclusion. Reciting it WILL embolden Surya. But, is it correct to do so? Is the question. If Surya owns 6th Bhaava or 12th Bhaava or 8th Bhaava or 3rd Bhaava or 11th Bhaava AND he's in the Raashi of Shanaischara or Raahu or has Drshti by them... then he is bound to do something bad.

You can understand it simply. Suppose you feed a person, he will get stronger right? Now, if you feed a bad person, he will also get stronger. But, clearly the second scenario is bad for you.

So, what should you do? Assuming that the second Jyotishi is correct, in relation to Drshti and Raashi in particular (the ability to see and Raashis are owned by Surya and 12 Aadityas) in relation to Surya, what you need to do is - either stop chanting it and/or chant a Shaanti Mantra/Strotra/Japa, instead.

If a bad guy is angry at you, what do you do? Do you feed him (or, his anger or capability)? Or do you calm him down?

Obviously, you do the latter.

A Stotra is not harmless, and it cannot be applied randomly. There's no panacea, especially as far as Navagrahas go. If you exalt a negative graha, you will suffer, and if you demote a positive one, you will also suffer.

---

Or at least, that would be the case if Aaditya Hrdaya was related to the Surya Graha.

Here's the Kshetra Chakra of Shri Raama based on Vaalmiki Raamaayana 1.18.8-11
[image: Mostly accurate Kshetra Chakra of Surya Avataara - Shri Raama]

The main thing to notice in relevance to Aaditya Hrdaya is the Lagna (Ascendant).

The Aaditya Hrdaya is for for Karka Lagna (and Raashi) individuals. Shri Raama had Karka Lagna with Chandra in Lagna, while Surya was in Uccha (exalted) position in Mesha (Aries) Raashi in 10th Bhaava (already in a great situation).

The 4th section of the body is the Hrdaya. Varuna rules Hrdaya, chandra, water etc.

Most people get this wrong, but believe it or not, **the Aaditya Hrdaya is not for *Surya* at all**, primarily. It is first and foremost for the Karka Raashi. Presumably, stotras like Aaditya jaanu or kroda or pada etc existed (for other Raashis) but since they weren't in the Raamaayana (as it wasn't applicable to Shri Raama), they haven't survived.

Raashis are ruled by Surya, Nakshatras are ruled by Chandra. Hopefully, you know this.

If you look at the meaning of the stotra, then you will figure this out pretty quickly. One factor is the name itself (hrdaya), naturally. Another factor is mention of Varuna (ApaamPati or similar names), 3 times at least (as opposed to Bhaga or Dhaataa or Vidhaata or Pushaa or Indra etc Aadityaas). And, most importantly, the first section itself:

**ततो युद्धपरिश्रान्तं समरे चिन्तया स्थितम् ।**
रावणं चाग्रतो दृष्ट्वा युद्धाय समुपस्थितम् ॥ १॥

Then, [mentally] exhausted from the war, he was situated in a state of worry...

Guess who worries?... Chandra. Surya cannot worry by nature, at all. Just as Ketu cannot think about positives or negatives of some materialistic pleasure, it's simply not in the nature.

This whole Stotram, is to support the Karka Raashi, which in turn is the Lagna, and contains Chandra (who happens to be the Lagna Naayaka,) so that Shri Raama gets out of his state of (mental) worry.

So, if your Karka Raashi is weak, then you should chant it. Trust me, 90% of it is completely unrelated to the Surya Graha, it's almost entirely related to the Raashi (of Karka).

---

This is not related to the question too much, but I will share some more 'secrets' about this Stotram:

पूजयस्वैनमेकाग्रो देवदेवं जगत्पतिम् ।
एतत् **त्रिगुणितं** जप्त्वा युद्धेषु विजयिष्यसि ॥ २६॥

'You should use this to worship, with a still and focused mind, the Deva of the Devas, the ruler of all creation, you should chant this three times and you will win in the war.

Why is it three times? It is 3 times specifically because Brhaspati (number 3, within vedic numer'ology') is in the Lagna. So, the Chandra is being supported via two fronts, by chanting it thrice. I won't go into more details.

आदित्यं प्रेक्ष्य जप्त्वा तु परं हर्षमवाप्तवान् ।
त्रिराचम्य शुचिर्भूत्वा धनुरादाय वीर्यवान् ॥ २९॥
["Gazing at the sun with devotion, he recited this hymn thrice and experienced bliss. Purifying Himself by **sipping water thrice**, He took up His bow with His mighty arms"](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/adityahriday.html).

Again, who is water? Varuna.

If for some reason, it's not enough to convince you, then the biggest bomb is the fact that Agyasta Rshi (the one who is presenting this whole stotram)'s father is Varuna(and Mitra) himself.

---

### To conclude:

**Anyone CAN chant this. The effect is boosting of the Karka Raashi** and has minimal relation to Surya, if you want to do something with Surya, then look for his things.

The reasons why you wouldn't chant it is if:

-The Karka Raashi has presence of a negative (depending on your Chakra) Graha in it (say, Raahu).

-The Karka Raashi is in a bad Bhaava (3,6,11 including 8,12 depending on chakra)

-You want to suppress the Karka Raashi's naayaka (Chandra)

-The Karka Raashi doesn't have presence of any Graha but has negative Drhsti from another.

**In which cases, avoid this like the plague.**

There's far far more nuance here and each person's Chakra is definitely unique and needs to be considered separately, but these general guidelines will keep you out of the vast majority of trouble that you may gain by chanting.

---

I'd like to point out that **Surya and Aaditya are DIFFERENT**, Surya is the Graha, as in the physical object, Aaditya is the Deva (or assimilation of 12 Devas) that rules the 12 Raashis. This is the Hrdaya (or fourth part/heart) of Aaditya, Surya DOES NOT have 12 Parts. The 12 parts of THE Aaditya manifest from Surya in the 12 months. Hopefully that is clear.

*Ignoring the complexity of Surya Naaraayana, who is not the exactly the Graha, but is a Deva... (but not the 12 Aadityas either)*

Also, in case you're wondering, the only reason the other Aadityas (and even unrelated entities like Pitrs) are mentioned is for the sake of receiving the power from Surya Naraaayana (who can half-correctly assumed to be an amalgamation of the 12). The Raashis are ruled by him altogether. So, different parts of him, are appealed to, going beyond just the 12 Aadityas. That's why the text, at one point mentions Brahmaa Vishnu and Shiva as being 'him'. That 'him' is Surya Naraayana. Beyond the 12 Aadityas and beyond the Graha, but also connected to them in a way.

---

Surya (or Chandra) being in Karka Raashi at the time of Raavana's death also plays a big factor, although I'm not aware of the exact dates during those times.